# Are linearly ordered topological spaces well-based?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

A [linearly-ordered topological space](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000133/) or LOTS is one whose topology admits a basis generated by open intervals of a total ordering of its points.

A [well-based](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000174/) space is one which admits a local basis of each point that is totally ordered by set inclusion.

It appeared to me that the former implied the latter, and I attempted to prove it via the following: for any point $p$ in a LOTS take (possibly transfinite) sequences $a:\Gamma\rightarrow[-\infty,p)$ and $b:\Gamma\rightarrow(p,\infty]$ for some ordinal $\Gamma$ which are monotonic and surjective with $a_0=-\infty$ and $b_0=\infty$. Then for any open interval $(c,d)$ containing $p$ there is an ordinal $\beta$ such that $c\le a_\beta<p<b_\beta\le d$, so $\{(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)\mid\alpha\in\Gamma\}$ is a local basis of $p$.

However, I got a response that a LOTS can be not well-based if there exists a point with different cofinalities on the left and the right, giving the example of $\omega_1+1+\omega*$ with the order topology (where $+$ denotes order concatenation and $\omega*$ the reverse order of $\omega$). This doesn't jibe with my understanding though, since there should exist exist monotonic surjections from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$ to make my argument work. Is this response wrong, or is there some shortcoming of my argument?

Comment: Where your argument is wrong that there doesn't have to exist ordinal $\Gamma$ which would be the same for both sides.

Answer (score 5):

Your argument is wrong because such ordinal $\Gamma$ and monotone surjections need not exist. For example, there is no (not necessarily strictly) increasing surjection $f:\omega_1\to \omega$, for otherwise by picking $\alpha_n\in f^{-1}(n)$ for each $n$, we'd obtain a countable cofinal subset of $\omega_1$. But cofinality of $\omega_1$ is uncountable.

Let $X = \omega_1+\{n' : n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$ and let $x = 0'$ be the point greater than all of points of $\omega_1$, where I decided to use $\{n' : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ instead of $1+\omega*$ for the clarity of argument. Here $n' < k'$ iff $n > k$.

Suppose that $U_t$, $t\in T$ is a linearly ordered base of $x$ where $T$ is a totally ordered set. We can write $T = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ where $T_n = \{t\in T : \min\{k : k'\in U_t\} = n\}$. Since we know that $k'\notin U_t$, $t\in T_n$ for $n < k$, we see that for $s\in T_k$ we must have $U_s\supsetneq U_t$ and so $t < s$ since the map $a\mapsto U_a$ is increasing. So $T_n$ decompose $T$ into disjoint sets such that, with notation $A < B$ iff $\forall_{a\in A, b\in B}\ a < b$, we have $T_n < T_k$ when $n < k$.

If we pick a sequence $t_k\in T_{n_k}$ (some of the $T_n$ can be empty, but $T_n\neq \emptyset$ for infinitely many $n$), this then means that $U_{t_k}$ is a countable local base at $x$. But this would then mean that $U_{t_k}\cap (\omega_1\cup \{0'\})$ is a countable local base at $x$. In other words, $\omega_1\cup \{0'\}\cong \omega_1+1$ would be first countable. But it isn't, since it has no countable local base at the point $\omega_1$ - again, for the reasons of uncountable cofinality.

You can see how this argument generalizes to show that if $X$ is an ordered space, then for $x\in X$ to have a totally ordered local base at $x$, we need to have that if the cofinality of $\{y\in X : y < x\}$ and coinitiality $\{y\in X : y > x\}$ is infinite, then they have to agree.

Comment: minor tweak for the last paragraph: "(or one of sets is empty, or the point $x$ has an immediate predecessor or has an immediate successor)"

Comment: @PatrickR Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no monotonic surjection $s:\kappa\to\lambda$ when $cf(\kappa)>\lambda$. To see this, we construct a cofinal map $f_s:\lambda\to\kappa$ by $f(\alpha)=\min\{\beta<\kappa:s(\beta)=\alpha\}$.

We then see that $f$ is cofinal: given $\beta<\kappa$, consider $s(\beta)+1<\lambda$. There is some minimal $\gamma<\kappa$ such that $s(\gamma)=s(\beta)+1$, so $f(s(\gamma))=\gamma$. Since $s$ is monotonic and $s(\gamma)>s(\beta)$, we have $\gamma>\beta$.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

(This proves the same thing as Jakobian's answer, but presented in the more general context of partially ordered sets.)

##### Some generalities about posets

Let $(P, \le)$ be a partially ordered set.  A subset $A\subseteq P$ is a *chain* if any two of its elements are comparable.  A subset $A\subseteq P$ is *cofinal* if every element of $P$ is less than or equal to some element of $A$.

If $P$ is totally ordered, there is a well-ordered cofinal subset of some cardinality $\kappa$.  The smallest such cardinal is the *cofinality* of $P$ and is a regular cardinal (or $1$ is the poset has a maximum element) and there is a strictly increasing (transfinite) sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ cofinal in $P$.

In a general (non-totally ordered) poset $P$ there may not exist a cofinal chain.  If $P$ has a cofinal chain, one says that $P$ *has true cofinality* (Jech, Set Theory, p. 461).  In that case, as shown in [In a poset with a cofinal chain, does every cofinal subset admit a cofinal chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885886), every cofinal subset $Q\subseteq P$ (considered as a poset in its own right) also has a cofinal chain.  And conversely, every cofinal chain in $Q$ is a cofinal chain in $P$.  So to determine if $P$ has true cofinality, it is enough to restrict attention to a suitably chosen cofinal subset.

(Note: if $P$ has true cofinality, all cofinal chains in $P$ have the same cofinality.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785132).)

##### Applying this to topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x$ be a point of $X$.

Consider the poset $\mathcal N$ consisting of all nbhds of $x$, ordered by reverse inclusion ($\supseteq$).

- A local base of nbhds of $x$ is precisely a cofinal subset of $\mathcal N$.
- $X$ being well-based at $x$ is equivalent to $\mathcal N$ having a cofinal chain; or equivalently, the existence in $(\mathcal N,\supseteq)$ of a cofinal strictly increasing sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mu}$ indexed by some regular cardinal $\mu$ (unless $x$ itself has a smallest nbhd).

---

Specializing to the case of LOTS, suppose $(X,\le)$ is a totally ordered set with the corresponding order topology.  And let $x\in X$.

If $x$ has no element to one side or has an immediate predecessor or an immediate successor, then it is easy to check $X$ is well-based at $x$ by considering intervals of the form $(a,x]$ or $[x,b)$.

Otherwise, $x$ has infinite cofinality $\kappa$ on its left (i.e., the cofinality of $(\leftarrow,x)$) and infinite (downward) cofinality $\lambda$ on its right (i.e., the cofinality of $(x,\rightarrow)$ ordered by $\ge$).  Then there is an increasing sequence $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ converging to $x$ from the left and a decreasing sequence $(b_\beta)_{\beta<\lambda}$ converging to $x$ from the right.  And the collection of intervals $(a_\alpha,b_\beta)$ forms a local base at $x$.  The corresponding poset ordered by reverse inclusion is isomorphic to the product poset $\kappa\times\lambda$ (ordered by $\langle\alpha_1,\beta_1\rangle \le \langle\alpha_2,\beta_2\rangle$ iff $\alpha_1\le\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1\le\beta_2$).

> **Proposition:** Let $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ be infinite regular cardinals.  The product poset $P=\kappa\times\lambda$ has true cofinality iff $\kappa=\lambda$.

*Proof:* If $\kappa=\lambda$, the diagonal $\{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle : \alpha<\kappa\}$ is a cofinal chain.

The rest of the proof uses the same argument used to show that the Dieudonné plank is not radial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821179)) or that the Tychonoff plank is not radial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789562)).

Assume $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are not equal, say $\kappa>\lambda$.  Suppose there is a strictly increasing cofinal sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mu}$ cofinal in $P$ and indexed by an infinite regular cardinal $\mu$.  Projecting to the first component gives the sequence $(\pi_1(x_\alpha))_\alpha$ cofinal in $\kappa$.  Therefore $\kappa=\text{cof}(\kappa)\le\mu$.  On the other hand, $P$ has cardinality $\kappa$, hence $\mu\le\kappa$.  So $\mu=\kappa$.

Now projecting to the second component give the sequence $(\pi_2(x_\alpha))_\alpha$ cofinal in $\lambda$.  So for each $\beta<\lambda$ there is some $\alpha<\mu$ with $\pi_2(x_\alpha)\ge\beta$ and since the sequence of $x_\alpha$ is increasing in $P$, the set $\{\alpha<\mu:\pi_2(x_\alpha)<\beta\}$ has cardinality less than $\lambda$.  And since every $\alpha$ belongs to one of these sets and $\lambda<\mu$, $\mu$ is a union of less than $\mu$ sets, each of cardinality less than $\mu$.  That is, $\mu$ is not a regular cardinal, which contradicts the regularity of $\kappa$.

---

And the final result for LOTS:

> **Theorem:** Let $(X,\le)$ be a totally ordered set with its order topology and let $x\in X$.  The topology on $X$ is *not* well-based at $x$ iff $x$ has infinite and unequal cofinalities on its left and right sides.

Stated equivalently, $X$ is well-based at $x$ iff $x$ has no element to its left or to its right, or $x$ has an immediate predecessor or immediate successor, or $x$ has infinite and equal cofinalities on both sides.